# Html Agility Pack - <option> inner text

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-select, html-agility-pack

I have problem with this html:

```
<select id="attribute1021" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" name="super_attribute[1021]">
<option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
<option value="281">001 Melaike</option>
<option value="280">002 Taronja</option>
<option value="289">003 Lill</option>
<option value="288">004 Chèn</option>
<option value="287">005 Addition</option>
<option value="286">006 Iskia</option>
<option value="285">007 Milele</option>
<option value="284">008 Cali</option>
<option value="283">009 Odessa</option>
<option value="282">010 Manaus</option>
<option value="303">011 Nartiss</option>
<option value="302">012 Curitiba</option>
<option value="301">013 Bogota</option>
<option value="300">014 Solèy</option>
<option value="299">015 Campinas</option>
<option value="298">016 Formosa</option>
<option value="297">017 Valencia</option>
<option value="296">018 Candu</option>
<option value="295">019 Medellín</option>
<option value="294">020 Incubo</option>
<option value="293">021 Belisama</option>
<option value="292">022 Amo</option>
<option value="291">023 Chimaira</option>
<option value="290">024 Matanza</option>
<option value="319">025 Baltimore</option>
</select>
```

With this code in C#

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in dok.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@class='required-entry super-attribute-select']/option"))
{
    sb.Append("V")
      .Append(y)
      .Append(">")
      .Append(node.InnerText)
      .Append("/V")
      .Append(y)
      .Append(">")
      .AppendLine();
}
```

But in inner text is only "Choose an Option..." .

Any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 9):

Html Agility Pack by default leaves option-Tags empty. To have it work you need remove the option-Tag from the list of elements that are left empty.

Just put the following somwhere before you load the Html.

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");

var dok = new HtmlDocument();
dok.Load("option.htm");
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var y = "";
foreach (HtmlNode node in dok.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@class='required-entry super-attribute-select']/option"))
{
 sb.Append("V")
      .Append(y)
      .Append(">")
      .Append(node.InnerText)
      .Append("/V")
      .Append(y)
      .Append(">")
      .AppendLine();
}
```

Comment: Just first option element ("Choose an Option...")

Comment: Edited my answer, that Code works for me. Note: option.htm contains just the Html you posted.

Comment: I suspect that the actual value of the option is populated as comment, not as text, as it isn't rendered on screen. The same happens with <script>, <style> etc tags. Try `//select[@class='required-entry super-attribute-select']/option/comment()` to grab the contents of the option tag. Also, install the HAP Explorer, it helps debug these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 5):

You need to get at the `#text` node. Try using this instead:

```
sb.Append("V")
  .Append(y)
  .Append(">")
  .Append(node.NextSibling.InnerText)
  .Append("/V")
  .Append(y)
  .Append(">")
  .AppendLine();
```

Comment: I used your sample snippet and the exact code of your `foreach`. Unless you are working against a larger document or somehow loading the `HtmlDocument` differently I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Light version of the code is 
'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument dok = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
dok.Load(strRead);

foreach (HtmlNode node in dok.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@class='required-entry super-attribute-select']/option/following-sibling::text()"))
{      sb.Append("<V").Append(y).Append(">").Append(node.InnerText).Append("</V").Append(y).Append(">").AppendLine();
}

return sb.ToString();'
where strRead is webpage..

Comment: You can edit your question to include the entire code section. But it seems like the issue is that I'm loading only the XML you posted in your question while you're working against an entire web page?

Comment: `.NextSibling.InnerText` +1

Answer (score 1):

Or you may change your XPath expression to `"//select[@class='required-entry super-attribute-select']/option/following-sibling::text()"`

Comment: Try to isolate the problem by first running the exact code you posted on the exact html part you posted. I can agree with Yuck's comment above that you're setup is somehow different.